# Emailing text input using external email app android

Tags: java, android

firstly I have a editText field which takes the users notes and I have a functioning button which opens up an external email app from my app. I want to know how to have the message of the email(from the editText field) already filled for the user when the email app opens.
I have provided code snippets of the relevant parts below. 
This is my onCreate method:

```
public class TakeNotes extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText tv;
Button btnSave; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.take_notes);
    tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    btnSave= (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
```

This is my OnClickListener:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
  //some other code for a different function
  case R.id.email:
            Intent emailIntent = new 
  Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Message");
            startActivity(emailIntent);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email 
  in:"));
```

I think it has to do with this line, but I am unsure what I need to add:

```
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Message");
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
EditText text;
Button btnSave;
String emailstring;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checking_intent);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            emailstring = text.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of your email");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , emailstring);
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(CheckingIntent.this, "There are no email app installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My app crashes when I add that. Do I need to add something to the onCreate method?